# Recursive merge sort doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I wrote a program which is supposed to perform a recursive merge sort, I firstly created a `fusion` method to merge two list using indexs

Here is the `fusion` method

```
def Fusion (L,d,f,m):
  aux=[]
  i_d=d
  i_m=m
  while (i_d<=m-1 and i_m<=f-1):
    if(L[i_d]<=L[i_m]):
        aux.append(L[i_d])
        i_d+=1
    else:
        aux.append(L[i_m])
        i_m+=1
  while (i_d<=m-1):
    aux.append(L[i_d])
    i_d+=1
  while (i_m<=f-1):
    aux.append(L[i_m])
    i_m+=1
  for j in range(len(aux)):
    L[j]=aux[j]
```

This method works correctly, I tested it with two sorted lists.

The `merge` method here

```
 def sort_fusion(T,a,b):
  if (a<b):
    m=(a+b)//2
    sort_fusion(T,a,m) 
    sort_fusion(T,m+1,b)
    Fusion(T,a,b,m)
```

To run the program

```
k1 =[3,1,0,9,1,2,6,8,5,7]
a=0
b=len(k1)
sort_fusion(k1,a,b)
```

The program gives this `[2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 1, 8, 5, 7]` as output giving this input `[3, 1, 0, 9, 1, 2, 6, 8, 5, 7]`

I can't understand the program's behaviour, when I comment the `sort_fusion(T,m+1,b)` instruction, its gives me this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9, 1]` as output, for me the algorithm is just fine, when I follow its progress.

Can anyone point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
L[j]=aux[j]
```

Here, you probably need

```
L[j + d] = aux[j]
```

The reason is that you are taking values from L, that start from the index d. When you write the auxiliary array back into L, you want to write the numbers to the same place.

Comment: Did you try changing `L[j]` to `L[j + d]` at the end of `Fusion`? This should fix your code.